# Upgrade magento cloud from 2.4.3p3 to magento 2.4.5

Tags: upgrade, magento2-cloud, magento2.4.5

since the magento cloud support can't reproduce the bug, so i ask this question. My local env is using

composer 2.1.8
php 8.1.0

when i run composer install

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/module-amazon 4.4.1, found magento/module-amazon[4.4.1] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib ^2.8, found mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib[2.8.39] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires magento/composer-root-update-plugin ^2.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/composer-root-update-plugin[2.0.2].
    - magento/composer-root-update-plugin 2.0.2 requires composer/composer ^1.0 || ^2.0 -> found composer/composer[1.10.26] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
  Problem 4
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.4.5 <2.4.6 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.4.5].
    - magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.4.5 requires fastly/magento2 ^1.2.34 -> found fastly/magento2[1.2.186] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
  Problem 5
    - magento/ece-tools[2002.1.0, ..., 2002.1.8] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.1.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/ece-tools[2002.1.9, ..., 2002.1.11] require colinmollenhour/credis ^1.6.0 -> found colinmollenhour/credis[1.11.1] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
    - Root composer.json requires magento/ece-tools ^2002.1 -> satisfiable by magento/ece-tools[2002.1.0, ..., 2002.1.11].
```

my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "magento/magento-cloud-template",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.4.3",
    "license": "OSL-3.0",
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
            "magento/magento-composer-installer": true,
            "magento/inventory-composer-installer": true,
            "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "magento/*": true
        }
    },
    "repositories": {
        "repo": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "^2.0.2",
        "magento/ece-tools": "^2002.1",
        "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": ">=2.4.5 <2.4.6",
        "magento/module-amazon": "4.4.1",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-pcntl": "Need for run processes in parallel mode"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "component_paths": {
            "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
            "components/jquery": [
                "lib/web/jquery.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
            ],
            "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
            "components/jqueryui": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
            ],
            "twbs/bootstrap": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"
            ],
            "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce_5"
        },
        "magento-force": true,
        "magento-deploystrategy": "copy"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "generate-schema": [
            "php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools schema:generate || true"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@generate-schema"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@generate-schema"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is related to authentication to magento repo.

You need to be sure you have defined correct username/password (globally or locally).

You can create file `auth.json` in your project and specify your personal credentials like:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "***your",
            "password": "***yourpass***"
        }
    }
}
```

Better to use the same credentials which are you using in Cloud

Comment: i've removed "magento/module-amazon": "4.4.1", and change to use php 7.4, the composer update is successful, the strange thing is the magento cloud support ask me to use php 8.1

Comment: It's a really strange. Anyway, you can try to create new project from https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/master/composer.json with PHP 8.1 and after add your extensions and check if they are compatible with PHP 8.1. In some cases you can use `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag as workaround